# Functions $u \in C^{0,1/2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ satisfy $\|u\|_{C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)} < \infty$

Tags: holder-spaces

In solving problem sheets for my upcoming functional analysis $2$ exam I encountered the following statement:

> Functions $u \in C^{0,1/2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ satisfy $\|u\|_{C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)} < \infty$.

Here $C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denotes the space of **Hölder continuous functions** for $0 < \alpha \leq 1$, i.e. $$C^{0,\alpha} := \{f \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^n) : [f]_{C^{0,\alpha}} < \infty\}$$ where $$[f]_{C^{}0,\alpha} := \sup_{x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n,x\neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|^\alpha}$$

What I tried: $$\|u\|_{C^0} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |u(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}|u(x) - u(y)| + |u(y)| \leq\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}|x - y|^{1/2} [u]_{C^{0,1/2}}+ |u(y)|$$ which does not help much

Comment: Isn't $u(x)=\sqrt {|x|}$ a counterexample?

Comment: @zhw. Thanks! Yes,  I also was very suspicious about this statement.

Comment: It seems that by definition, you are saying $C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb R^n) \subset C^0(\mathbb R^n).$ How are you defining $C^0(\mathbb R^n)$? Is this all continuous functions $f: \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, or is it just the continuous functions $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $\|f\|_{C^0(\mathbb R^n)} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n} \lvert f(x) \rvert < \infty$? In the latter case, this claim is trivially true; in the former case it is false as zhw's example shows.

Comment: @User8128 My notes are not very clear about this...but it is stated that if $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded, then $$\|f\|_{C^0} + [f]_{C^{0,\alpha}}$$ is a norm on $C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)$. Thus I suspect, that we are just dealing with continuous functions and not bounded ones, since otherwise this would also be a norm for $\Omega$ unbounded.